# Fix speaker volume in alsamixer

Tags: sound, 15.10, alsa, system-settings

I get bad sound quality while using Ubuntu.
When I adjust the speaker volume in alsamixer it sounds good.
But the problem is that volume level won't stay fixed.
As soon as I change the master volume level, the speaker volume gets back to 100%.

[image: alsamixer screenshot]